# display frames from a saved video frame by frame with a time delay between each frame using OpenCV, none of the different methods I've tried work

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I've been trying to display frames from a saved video at the keypress 'l' frame by frame with a time delay between each frame, none of the different methods I've tried seem to work. I've used so far time.sleep, nested while loops, if conditions using the elapsed time as a constraint and also the cv2.waitKey function itself. the code itself howeverdisplays the saved video at a frame rate far greater than the actual saved video itself. Does someone have experience with openCV and could perhaps point me in the right direction towards achieving what I've been trying to do? I would really appreciate it as it's been a real brain racker for a few days now and am a beginner with it since i started a few weeks ago. :) Here is just the part of the entire code that is responsible for the writing of the video at keypress 'd' and the playback at keypress 'l':

```
#for recording video of aufnahme
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    filename2 = 'output_{}.avi'.format(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"))
    # Set the screen size
    screen_size = (1920, 1080)
    fps = 2
    
    # Create a video writer object
    video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(filename2, fourcc, fps, screen_size)
    while flag==DSA:           
             ret, live = camera.read()  #read live feed
             gray = cv2.cvtColor(live, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
             key=cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
              # Get the current screen frame
             screen_frame = pyautogui.screenshot()
             

             # Convert the screen frame to a numpy array
             screen_frame_np = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screen_frame), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

             if ret:
                 # Display the frame if the 'r' key is pressed
                 #key=cv2.waitKey(1)  & 0xFF #to run live feed smoothly
                 if key ==ESCAPE_KEY:
                  exit()
                 if key==ord('n'):  
                     show_notification("Native mode")
                     flag=False
                     key=cv2.waitKey(1)
                 if key==ord('s'):
                      path = r'C:/Users/skhandelwal/Desktop/Dsa Simulator'
                      os.chdir(path)
                      target = pyautogui.getActiveWindow()
                      location = (
                      target.left,
                      target.top,
                      target.width,
                      target.height
                      )
                      image = pyautogui.screenshot(region=location)
                      now = datetime.now() #get current date and time
                      dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
                      image.show()
                      filename1 = 'Screenshot_DSA_' + dt_string  +'.jpg'
                      image=image.save(filename1)                        
        
                 if show_video:
                     cv2.imshow('angio sim', gray)  #create a blank window
                     #key=cv2.waitKey(1)
                     # Wait for a key press and check if the 'r' key is pressed
                     key=cv2.waitKey(15)  & 0xFF #for making the live feed run smoothly
                 if key == ord('r'): #if condition for keypress r
                     show_video = True  #change value of flag
                     bg=None
                     key_pressed=True
                     now = datetime.now() #get current date and time
                     dt_string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
                     filename = 'Backgroundat1fps_'+ dt_string +'.jpg'
                     #key=cv2.waitKey(1)           
                 if key_pressed and  not keyboard.is_pressed('r'):
                     bg=gray
                     #print(bg.shape)
                     font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
                     now_without_ms= now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

                     cv2.putText(bg, str(now_without_ms), (20, 40), font, 2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
                     maske=live
                     gray_mask=cv2.cvtColor(live, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
                     key_pressed=False# to freeze live feed
                 if key==ord('a'):
                     show_notification("Already in DSA mode")  
                     flag=DSA                              
                 if key==ord('m'):
                     show_notification("Roadmap mode")
                     flag =Roadmap
                 elif not keyboard.is_pressed('r'):
                     show_video = False
                 if key == ord('d'):
                     diff = cv2.absdiff(gray, bg)
                     inverted_diff = cv2.bitwise_not(diff)
                     diff_colormap = cv2.applyColorMap(diff, cv2.COLORMAP_BONE)

                     # create a light gray background image with the same shape as inverted_diff
                     background = np.full(inverted_diff.shape, 0, dtype=np.uint8)

                     # blend the inverted_diff and background images
                     alpha = 0.8
                     blended_image = cv2.addWeighted(inverted_diff, alpha, background, 1-alpha, 0)

                     cv2.imshow('angio sim', blended_image)
                     # Write the current screen frame to the output video
                     screen_frame = pyautogui.screenshot()

                     # Convert the screen frame to a numpy array
                     screen_frame_np = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screen_frame), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

                     video_writer.write(screen_frame_np)
                 if key == ord('l'):
                     # Open the saved video file
                     saved_video = cv2.VideoCapture(filename2)
                     show_video1=True
                     saved_video.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, fps)
                     frame_count=0
                     key=0
                     
                     while show_video1:
                            # Read the next frame from the saved video file
                            ret, frame = saved_video.read()
                            print(ret)
                            start_time=time.time()
                            if ret:
                                 
                                 cv2.imshow('angio sim', frame)
                                 frame_count += 1
                                 key=cv2.waitKey(1)
                                 print (time.time())
                                 while time.time()-start_time<=1:
                                        print(time.time())
                                
                                        print (start_time)
                                        print(time.time()-start_time)
                                        if key==27:
                                          exit()
                                        if key==ord('l'):
                                          break   
                            else:
                                 print(key)
                                 
                                 if key==27:
                                        exit() 
                                 else:
                                  # End of video file
                                  show_video1 = False
                                  saved_video.release()
                                  key=-1
                                  print("End of video file ({} frames)".format(frame_count))
                            if show_video1 and not key==ord('l'):
                                 show_video1=False
                                 print('L_released')
                                 key=-1
                                    
                 else:
                  key=cv2.waitKey(1)
```